# Laravel is not connecting to MySQL from Docker container but PDO is

Tags: php, laravel, docker, mariadb, database-connection

I have a docker container running a Laravel 7.0 with MariaDB 10.3.23 project that is triggering the Exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `table` where `id` = 1)
```

whenever I try to run any Eloquent code!

But the weird part is that if inside any controller I run any SQL:

```
$config = config('database.connections.mysql'); // I used like so to ensure it's taken from configs!
try {
    $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
    foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * from table LIMIT 10') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

it prints out the correct output!

Just in case, my .env file is supposed to be correct since it works with PDO:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3036
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=app
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have clean all configs:

```
docker exec -it php-app php artisan optimize:clear
```

And got no errors!

I think it should be something obvious that I am missing, otherwise quite a weird bug!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the port, or put in the correct port of **3306** instead of 3036.

Comment: Yep. I got that mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As observed by @aynber in the comments. I had a typo in the port.